# Phalcon: How work setTemplateAfter('main') function?

Tags: templates, view, controller, program-entry-point, phalcon

I'm analysing **invo** project from phalcon samples. in the **indexController** and in the **initialize()** function I have a problem for understanding this line:

> $this->view->setTemplateAfter('main');

What is the **'main'**?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `main` is a template which is processed after the current template.

Its location is under /views/layouts (the file is [here](https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/views/layouts/main.volt))

Also have a look at the [using templates](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html?highlight=setTemplateAfter#using-templates) section in the documentation.